# CASE expression when with multiple column order

Tags: sql, oracle, case-when

Posted value if 0 then, make the order according to these columns: `isl_tar`, `isl_saat`, `ref_kod`, `isl_ref`, `kayit_no`

Posted value if 1 then make the order according to this column: `tutar`

[image: plsql table ss]

This script is not working:

I want to sort by the second case

```
select t.*
  from TEMP_HESAP_HAREKET t

 order by case 1
            when 0 then
             TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ISL_TAR, 'YYYYMMDD') ||
                       SUBSTR(ISL_SAAT, 1, 2) || SUBSTR(ISL_SAAT, 4, 2))
          end asc,
          REF_KOD asc,
          ISL_REF asc,
          KAYIT_NO asc,
          case 1 
            when 1 then
              tutar end
```

Comment: What is not working exactly? The final `case` statement is incomplete. Does `hareket` have a column named `"1"`?

Comment: I want to sort by the second case

select t.*
  from TEMP_HESAP_HAREKET t

 order by case 1
            when 0 then
             TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ISL_TAR, 'YYYYMMDD') ||
                       SUBSTR(ISL_SAAT, 1, 2) || SUBSTR(ISL_SAAT, 4, 2))
          end asc,
          REF_KOD asc,
          ISL_REF asc,
          KAYIT_NO asc,
          case 1 
            when 1 then
              tutar end

Comment: `case 1 when 0` will never be true. The `1` in `order by 1` can't be extended to `case` expressions.

Comment: Presumably *"posted value"* refers to the mysterious `1` in the CASE statement. But where does that value actually come? What "posts" it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the value after the `CASE` gets put there somehow, maybe by some application which fires the statement.

Then you could order by five `CASE`.

If the value is `0` then return the respective column from your list of columns you want to sort in case of a `0`.

In the first `CASE` return `tutar` if the value is `1`. In all the other `CASE`, if the value is `1`, return always the same value or none at all (`NULL`) which will be the default anyway, if you don't have a `WHEN` for it in there at all.

```
ORDER BY CASE ?
           WHEN 0 THEN
             ISL_TAR
           WHEN 1 THEN
             TUTAR
         END ASC,
         CASE ?
           WHEN 0 THEN
             ISL_SAAT
         END ASC,
         CASE ?
           WHEN 0 THEN
             REF_KOD
         END ASC,
         CASE ?
           WHEN 0 THEN
             ISL_REF
         END ASC,
         CASE ?
           WHEN 0 THEN
             KAYIT_NO
         END ASC
```

The `?` have to be replaced with the `0` or `1`.

However, if there is an application placing the values after the `CASE`, it might be a "cleaner" (easier to read, understand and maintain) way to make it change the complete `ORDER BY` expression instead of putting the `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
 order by (case 1 when 1 then tutar end),  -- handle that case first
           TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ISL_TAR, 'YYYYMMDD') ||
                       SUBSTR(ISL_SAAT, 1, 2) || SUBSTR(ISL_SAAT, 4, 2))
            REF_KOD asc,
            ISL_REF asc,
            KAYIT_NO asc
```

I assume the expression on `isl_tar` is correct.  It seems like a simple column reference would suffice.